# How can I convert this function from ExceptT to Except in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception, monad-transformers

I got very confused with `Except`, specially since there is no good tutorial around the web. I don't know how can I convert this function from `ExceptT` to `Except`:

```hs
data Error = Empty deriving (Show)

badFunction :: ExceptT Error IO ()
badFunction = throwError Empty

main :: IO ()
main = do
    caught_result <- runExceptT badFunction
    case caught_result of
      Left _ -> putStrLn "caught some error"
      Right _ -> putStrLn "no errors were caught"
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to an `ExceptT`? For `Except` it means that `IO` should be `Identity` instead in `ExceptT Error IO ()`, so `ExceptT Error Identity ()`?

Comment: *Monad transformers* are a bit a more advanced topic. So perhaps this helps: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html

Comment: I already know monad transformers... the problem is that I don't know how to use Except, only ExceptT, that's my question/problem

Comment: well since you use it in an `IO ()` this forces it to ben an `IO`, since `runExceptT :: ExceptT e m a -> m (Either e a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

```
badFunction :: ExceptT Error IO ()
badFunction = throwError Empty
```

which suggests that it does `IO`. But it doesn't do any `IO`. As Willem Van Onsem points out, one option is to indicate that by using `Except` instead:

```
badFunction :: Except Error ()
```

By the definition of `Except`, this is identical to

```
badFunction :: ExceptT Error Identity ()
```

There is a third option:

```
badFunction :: Monad m => ExceptT Error m ()
```

This gives you full flexibility!

```
runExcept badFunction :: Either Error ()
runExceptT badFunction :: Monad m => m (Either Error ())
```

So if you choose, you can write

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    caught_result <- runExceptT badFunction
    case caught_result of
      Left _ -> putStrLn "caught some error"
      Right _ -> putStrLn "no errors were caught"
```

Whatever you think is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason `badFunction` should be an `ExceptT Error IO ()` is because `runExceptT` has type [**`runExceptT :: ExceptT e m a -> m (Either e a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:runExceptT). Since your main has type `main :: IO ()`, this means that `runExceptT badFunction` needs to be `IO …`, hence the `m` in the `ExceptT e m a` should be `IO`.

But you do not per se need this, your `badFunction` does not do any `IO`, so you can define it as an `Except`:

```
badFunction :: Except Error ()
badFunction = throwE Empty
```

Then you can use it in an `IO ()` by using `runIdentity` to obtain the value out of the identity, and then use `pure` to "*wrap*" the result in an `IO`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    caught_result <- pure (runIdentity (runExceptT badFunction))
    case caught_result of
      Left _ -> putStrLn "caught some error"
      Right _ -> putStrLn "no errors were caught"
```

But then we can just use a `let …` clause in the `main` and remove the `pure`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let caught_result = runIdentity (runExceptT badFunction)
    case caught_result of
      Left _ -> putStrLn "caught some error"
      Right _ -> putStrLn "no errors were caught"
```

As [@JonPurdy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290526/how-can-i-convert-this-function-from-exceptt-to-except-in-haskell/62290919?noredirect=1#comment110168768_62290919), the combination of `runIdentity` and `runExceptT` is [**`runExcept :: Except e a -> Either e a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:runExcept), so we can rewrite this to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let caught_result = runExcept badFunction
    case caught_result of
      Left _ -> putStrLn "caught some error"
      Right _ -> putStrLn "no errors were caught"
```

Comment: And of course the combination of `runIdentity` and `runExceptT` can be replaced with just [`runExcept`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:runExcept)

Comment: thank you for the explication of `runExcept` it really helped me in purescript